# How can i follow link after loggin in with scrapy Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling with scrapy. The point is that after logging in when i user scrapy.http.HtmlResponse to follow collector is returning emptiness.
I used all in scrapy.http.~.

```
import scrapy


class AMTSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amt_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://amtbox.us/index.php/access/user/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'FormUserLogin[login]:': 'my_name', 'FormUserLogin[password]': 'my_pass'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        main_url = 'http://amtbox.us'
        track_board = main_url + response.xpath('//div[@id="mainmenu"]').\
            xpath('//a[contains(@href, "tracking")]/@href').extract_first()
        board = scrapy.http.(track_board)
        table = board.css('div.main')

        # table = board.xpath('/*')
        print('RESULT', table)
```

What i am doing wrong???

Comment: Check the response contents you get after logging in (`response.text`, maybe write it into a file). My first guess is that you are failing to log in in the first place.

Comment: you can use the `open_in_browser(response)` to make sure you are logged in

Comment: I am surely logged in. But anyway i am getting empty collector.